# demerging cells followed by merging in tables

Tags: tables, multirow, multicolumn

[image]
Here is my code to make this table. But it does not go well.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\fontsize{10}{10}\selectfont
\caption{Comparison }
\vskip .25in
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|}\\\cline{2-5}
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}
 & A & B & C & D\\\hline
\multirow {3}{*}{N} & E & F & \multirow{3}{*}{G} & \multirow{3}{*}{H}\\\cline{2-3}
&&I & J \\\cline{2-3}
&&K & L \\\cline{2-3}


\end{tabular}
\label{tab:two}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Thank you.

Comment: The first \\ is wrong, and it should be `& I & J & &` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what `\multirow` is for:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{| c | p{1cm} | p{1.5cm} | p{5cm} | p{3cm} |}
\cline{2-5}
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & A & B & C & D \\
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &   &   &   &   \\
\hline
N & E & F & G & H \\
  &   &   &   &   \\
\cline{2-3}
  & I & J &   &   \\
  &   &   &   &   \\
\cline{2-3}
  & K & L &   &   \\
  &   &   &   &   \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I feel that you want your table span the whole `linewidth`, so here is a solution using `tabularx`. The sum of the widths `|L{.1}|L{.6}|L{.8}|L{2.2}|L{1.3}|` should add up to `5` because you have five columns. The sum, in general, should be equal to the number of columns. The values `.1, .6, .8, ...` are chosen in a relative manner to give the desired relative widths of the columns.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\hsize=#1\hsize\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|L{.1}|L{.6}|L{.8}|L{2.2}|L{1.3}|}
\cline{2-5}
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & A & B & C & D \\
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &   &   &   &   \\ \hline
N                     & E & F & G & H \\
                      &   &   &   &   \\ \cline{2-3}
                      & I & J &   &   \\
                      &   &   &   &   \\ \cline{2-3}
                      & K & L &   &   \\
                      &   &   &   &   \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]